# Rails migration unique columns together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating Rails Model that I'll make polymorphic associations with. In the migration I have the following index and want these columns to be **unique together**. I've read that you can make columns **unique together**, but I want to ensure that I understand what this means.

```
add_index :addresses, [:addressable_type, :addressable_id], :unique => true
```

Let's say `addressable_id` is equal to 1 in two cases, but one type is `a` and another is `b`. This won't violate the unique requirement, right? I want to make sure this considers both columns to determine uniqueness. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you understand this correctly. To violate unique requirement both :addressable_type and :addressable_id should be equal. Syntax is ok too.

Comment: Syntax is OK but Rails do not work on uniqueness of combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thats right. The uniqueness is for the pair not for each value. You can insert "1-a" and "1-b", but not "1-a" a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it right, but the uniqueness check is in the database, not in your code.

You will want to have a uniqueness check in the code as well (a validation will probably do it.) Otherwise, PostgreSQL (or whatever database you're in) will return an error the second time you add a [1, a] combo and Rails will translate that into an error of its own. (Then you get a 500 error returned.)

You may also rescue and verify that this is the error if you want to validate that way, but you have to be careful not to rescue too much.